# Flutter + Firebase + Google SigIn

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

Im getting the error:

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null

I have done almost everything i founded...

1. SHA1 and SHA256 (debug mode)
2. Created the credentials on Google
3. Updated google services plugin and gradle in the build.gradle
4. Added the class path of the google-service and apply de plugin in build.gradle
5. Added e-mail support on FireBase
6. Added my e-mail, as support e-mail in configurations
7. Lots and lots of 'flutter clean'

It is working on iOS simulator but not on my Android device.
I followed the 'recipe' for SigIn With Google and Flutter... and nothing is solving my problem.

Debug mode on VSCode is showing error, when i call the sigIn() method:

Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null))

Thanks in advance for reading and giving some time.

**android/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle:**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to put something important in your .gradle files.

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` must be in android/build.gradle, and

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` must be in android/app/build.gradle

Comment: I will update my question, but i already did those steps. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you use firebase-auth? If yes, then you maybe missed 
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
at android/app/build.gradle

Comment: I added and run the following commands:

cd android

gradle signingReport

cd ios

pod cache clean --all

pod deintegrate --verbose

pod setup --verbose

pod install --verbose

flutter clean

Still not working...

Comment: HowTos says that `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` must be at end of android/app/build.gradle, not in the middle. Can you try this with flutter clean?

Comment: I changed the place of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and still the same error.